# How to properly order columns in a QTreeView based on a list as input

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtreeview

Basically I am displaying a QTreeView with 20 columns. I want the user to re-arrange the columns and push a save button to store the ordering as a list in an ini-file. On starting up the program, I want to re-order the columns based on the settings from the ini-file.

I am storing the original colum orders as list in "list_origin".
The desired order is in "list_custom".
E.g.

```
list_origin=['From', 'Subject', 'Date']
list_custom=['Date', 'Subject', 'From']
```

Now the problem is, when I move columns with the model headers moveSection() command, the original indexes are sometimes not correct anymore, because the columns might get inserted in between and thus lose their origin position index.

See example below: pushing the button "Rearrange cols to Date/Subject/From" will create an undesired order of the columns. How to arrange the colums in the desired order, based on the list_custom?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# file: treeView_FindCol.py

import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
def find_col_by_name(tree_obj, col_name: str) -> int:
    """ Returns found column position as integer, else -1 """
    pos_found: int = -1
    model = tree_obj.model()
    if model:
        for col in range(model.columnCount()):
            header = model.headerData(col, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole)
            if str(header) == col_name:
                pos_found = col
    return pos_found
def find_col_by_index(tree_obj, col_index: int) -> int:
    """ Returns found column position as integer, else -1 """
    pos_found: int = -1
    model = tree_obj.model()
    header = tree_obj.header()

    pos_found = header.visualIndex(col_index)
    header_txt = model.headerData(pos_found, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole)

    return pos_found

class App(QWidget):
    FROM, SUBJECT, DATE = range(3)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 Treeview Example - pythonspot.com'
        self.left = 800
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 240
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        pushButton = QPushButton("Rearrange cols to Date/Subject/From")

        groupBox = QGroupBox("Inbox")
        treeView = QTreeView()
        treeView.setRootIsDecorated(False)
        treeView.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

        pushButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.rearrange_column_layout(treeView))

        dataLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        dataLayout.addWidget(treeView)
        dataLayout.addWidget(pushButton)

        groupBox.setLayout(dataLayout)

        model = self.createMailModel(self)
        treeView.setModel(model)
        self.addMail(model, 'service@github.com', 'Your Github Donation','03/25/2017 02:05 PM')
        self.addMail(model, 'support@github.com', 'Github Projects','02/02/2017 03:05 PM')
        self.addMail(model, 'service@phone.com', 'Your Phone Bill','01/01/2017 04:05 PM')
        self.addMail(model, 'service@abc.com', 'aaaYour Github Donation','03/25/2017 02:05 PM')
        self.addMail(model, 'support@def.com', 'bbbGithub Projects','02/02/2017 03:05 PM')
        self.addMail(model, 'service@xyz.com', 'cccYour Phone Bill','01/01/2017 04:05 PM')

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(groupBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.show()

    def createMailModel(self,parent):
        model = QStandardItemModel(0, 3, parent)
        model.setHeaderData(self.FROM, Qt.Horizontal, "From")
        model.setHeaderData(self.SUBJECT, Qt.Horizontal, "Subject")
        model.setHeaderData(self.DATE, Qt.Horizontal, "Date")
        return model

    def addMail(self,model, mailFrom, subject, date):
        model.insertRow(0)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.FROM), mailFrom)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.SUBJECT), subject)
        model.setData(model.index(0, self.DATE), date)

    def rearrange_column_layout(self, treeView):
        print("restore_column_layout() called.")

        list_custom: list = ['Date', 'Subject', 'From']
        list_origin: list = []
        model = treeView.model()
        header = treeView.header()
        col_count = model.columnCount()
        for col_search_index in range(col_count):
            col_found = header.visualIndex(col_search_index)
            header_txt = model.headerData(col_search_index, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.DisplayRole)
            list_origin.append(header_txt)
        print(f"{list_origin=}")
        print(f"{list_custom=}")
        pos_custom: int = 0
        pos_origin_last: int = 0
        for item_custom in list_custom:
            pos_origin: int = 0
            for item_origin in list_origin:
                if item_custom == item_origin:
                    msg_txt = f"moving col '{item_origin}' from {pos_origin} to {pos_custom}."
                    print(msg_txt)
                    QMessageBox.information(self, f"{item_origin}", msg_txt)
                    header.moveSection(pos_origin, pos_custom)
                    pos_origin_last = pos_origin
                pos_origin += 1
            pos_custom += 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to set the column ordering based on an input list

"list_origin" contains the header names in original order, e.g.
list_origin=['From', 'Subject', 'Date']

"list_custom" is the desired order of the columns in my QTreeView, e.g.
list_custom=['Date', 'Subject', 'From']

Now I am iterating over the custom list, and want to put the columns based on this positions with header moveSection().

So the algorithm basically is:

step1: start with index 0 of the custom list, it's "Date"

step2: get the position of "Date" from origin list, which is 2.

step3: call moveSection(2,0)

Trace output:

moving col 'Date' from 2 to 0.

moving col 'Subject' from 1 to 1.

moving col 'From' from 0 to 2.

But anyway the result is "From"/"Subject"/"Date" (!) and not as desired "Date"/"Subject"/"From".

Comment: I don't understand your question, explain your sentence better: *the original indexes get invalid during the operation because some columns from the right might get inserted to the left.* it's not enough with: `def rearrange_column_layout(self, treeView):
        header = treeView.header().moveSection(0, 2)`

Comment: Thanks for asking.

Comment: Maybe you are aware of an easier way to do this...
Basically I am displaying a QTreeView with 20 columns.
I want the user to re-arrange the columns and push a save button to store the ordering as a list in an ini-file.
On starting up the program, I want to re-order the columns based on the settings from the ini-file.

Comment: You have an XY problem (I think that on some occasion I already explained what that type of question was, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), I can try to implement the objective that you indicate in your comment but unfortunately that is not what your question indicates, if you reformulate it then I would try to help you

Comment: Thanks for caring. I've tried my best to be as precise as possible and reformulated the question.

Comment: you point to an example that does not work (A, B, C, D, E) but the code you provide does not demonstrate this, you can provide the MRE that proves what you indicate. I hope that if the OP points to X then it shows a code that proves it.

Comment: Adapted description to the code example.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with MRE?

Comment: You have been on the site for more than a year and do not know what an MRE is; [mre]?

Comment: I was not aware of the abbreviation, sorry. I think the posted code in fact is the MRE.
I explained what I want to achieve.
You can run the code. You can see that it's not working as intended. I am willing to provide what's missing, but I cannot see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic is to obtain the index of each element at the time of the iteration since the visual order is changing within the loop:

```
def rearrange_column_layout(self, treeView):
    to_list = ["Date", "Subject", "From"]

    header = treeView.header()
    model = treeView.model()
    for i, c in enumerate(to_list[:-1]):
        from_list = [
            model.headerData(header.logicalIndex(visual_index), Qt.Horizontal)
            for visual_index in range(header.count())
        ]
        j = from_list.index(c)
        header.moveSection(j, i)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works indeed!
"The logic is to obtain the index of each element at the time of the iteration" - That's genius!